# Is ergonomically correct to let the backrest unlocked?

Tags: ergonomics

My ergonomic advisor recommended me to let the backrest of the chair unlocked, and play with the tension adjustment till I find a position in which I'm supported by the backrest.

However my issue is that if I find such "balance point" I'm basically stuck in one position: I cannot lean back because the backrest will offer some resistance, and I cannot lean forward because I will not have enough support.

So I was wondering if this is a good piece of advice that is supported by any research.

Comment: It is unclear if your ergonomic advisor implied that you should eventually find the _one_ position that you should stick to, or to find _a_ position that suits you without particularly excluding the possibility of changing position once in a while. If you're not sure what your ergonomic advisor meant, **ask them**. We don't know what's in their head either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Nobody knows.

I doubt you will find any good advice supported by research. Ergonomics and chairs and seating positions is notoriously pseudoscientific - even hypothetic claims that any well defined seating position is somehow linked to any S.M.A.R.T. measure of ergonomics is... well, hard to find. Usually they are ill-defined and measure something unrelated or fluffy ("back pains" is one of the least specific symptoms there is, alongside "tiredness" and "headache") and then proceed to make extremely specific recommendations based on an internet survey of 11 people and a cat.

Where science lacks, commonsense reigns: If it hurts, change your position. If it feels better sitting in one way than another, use that. If it ain't broken, don't fix it.